# Exception handling in App Insights TelemetryInitializer

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm adding several custom properties to my AppInsights events using `Initialize` method of `ITelemetryInitializer`. Some of them are retrieved from the database or other sources which might fail. The question is, are there any official recommendations from the developers on whether or not a `try-catch` clause should be included inside of `Initialize` method?

From what I've observed, throwing an exception inside the method doesn't prevent telemetry from appearing, though the custom properties cannot be seen, as expected. Can I rely on this behaviour? Does it somehow affect performance that I don't handle exceptions manually and let AppInsights' code handle them instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends, doesn't it. If the telemetry initializer adds multiple custom properties and the first one in line fails with an exception, do you want to try to add the others. If so, put a try/catch around each custom property.

If it is just a single property, or all should not be added as soon as the first one fails then you could choose not to handle the exception. In my opinion however, I would want to have control over the exception propagation and choose for handling  them myself. (and maybe ignore them with an empty catch, depending on the situation)

Ignoring them completely may give troubles in the future when the SDK for example is altered to not send the telemetry to App Insights when a telemetry initializer fails with an unhandled exception. At least if you decide to go this route try take a peek in the source code of the SDK to see what happens with the unhandled exception.

Comment: I've come to the same conclusions you have and I definitely don't want to rely on this behaviour unless it's documented somewhere, i.e. 'Any exception from ITelemetryInitializer.Initialize is swallowed by the SDK. Catch exceptions manually if you want to perform additional actions'. Basically, I'm looking for an official statement or documentation from MS, for instance like Serilog does for enrichers, clearly stating that their exceptions are swallowed and written to self log by design.

Comment: As to multiple properties, I've decided to use separate Initializers for that purpose so the choice is between a `try-catch` with an empty catch surrounding the whole method body or no `try-catch` at all.

Comment: About that official documentation, I would not count on finding it. These SKD's are globally documented but I've never seen it documented to such detailed level. You best best is the sourcecode itself (https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home) or ask for an official statement on one of the GitHub repo pages.

Comment: I've just talked to Azure support and they weren't able to provide any clear guidance either. So I guess explicit try-catch is a way to go.